# Ansible - use host IP as a variable for file copies

Tags: ansible, configuration-management

I am looking for a way for config management with Ansible.

I have the structure repo/1.2.3.4/file.conf.

Can Ansible get the IP 1.2.3.4 per host and deploy the file to the host?
Using a variable would make the config easier.

```
- copy: src=/repo/$IP/file.conf dest=/etc/file.conf owner=foo group=foo mode=0644
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can do that with Ansible. Ansible geathers facts of the system before every run. You can check these facts about the system with the `setup` module like this:

```
ansible hostname -m setup
```

Check [the documentation](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_variables.html#information-discovered-from-systems-facts) for more information.

You are looking for the default ip4 address I assume. Which would be `ansible_default_ipv4`. You can access the value of the variable like this:

```
- copy: src=/repo/{{ ansible_default_ipv4.address }}/file.conf dest=/etc/file.conf owner=foo group=foo mode=0644
```